# Adjust Text in Table Cell Issue

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a table using the code below, but I have an issue visualized in the figure in "Corrida" number 14. I was searching about this and saw if I put a text, it adjust itself.

PD: I'm using \multicolumn because I want to see if the table looks good with different aligns instead center.

PD2: The figure below shows a table that exceeds the margin of the format used (Springer fomat)

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|ccccc|}
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\Large\textbf{Resultados del Modo Online con el filtro IIR}}} \\
        & & &  & \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\large\textbf{Datos}} & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Fecha} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{14/12/2016}   \\ \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\# Repeticiones} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{5}  \\                                        
        \hline
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Corrida}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{¿Acertó?}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Evidencia}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Observaciones}} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Teléfono} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sin Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Ventana} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sin Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Televisor} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sin Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Lámpara} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sin Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Teléfono} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sin Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Radio} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Televisor} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Radio} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{9} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Lámpara} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Teléfono} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Lámpara} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Televisor} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{13} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Radio} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Lámpara} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Televisor} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{16} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Televisor} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{17} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Lámpara} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si - No} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{18} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Teléfono} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Puerta} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{20} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Lámpara} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Si} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Video} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Con Luz / El sujeto indicó cual queria ver.} \\
        \hline
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Observaciones}} \\
        \multicolumn{5}{|l|}{Experimento realizado sin tapones.} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Sesión 04.}
    \label{tabla:finalonline}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: You should probably use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and an `X` column for the last one that is too wide.